# CascadeWindows but except for the caller window

Tags: winapi, interop, pinvoke

Can I cascade all windows with this method

```
        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        public static extern ushort CascadeWindows(
            HWND hwndParent,
            uint wHow,
            ref RECT lpRect,
            uint cKids,
            ref HWND lpKids
        );
```

but except for the current window that called the method (or a Window that I have an HWND of)?

```
CascadeWindows(NULL, MDITILE_ZORDER, NULL, 0, NULL); // "Cascade windows"
```

**edit:**
I tried this but It only moved the main window instead of all others:

```
        Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(0, 0, 1740, 1010);
        var arrayRange = Process.GetProcesses()
            .Where(x => 
                !string.IsNullOrEmpty(x.MainWindowTitle) &&
                !x.MainWindowTitle.Contains("Main Window")
            )
            .Select(x => x.Handle).ToArray();

        user32.CascadeWindows(nullptr, 0, ref rect, 0, ref arrayRange); // "Cascade windows"
```

And also corrected the function declaration

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")] public static extern ushort CascadeWindows( IntPtr hwndParent, uint wHow, ref Rectangle lpRect, uint cKids, IntPtr[] lpKids);
```

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, neither TileWindows()?

Comment: Use the last two parameters to specify the windows that you want to cascade. If you want to exclude the current window, then remove it from your array before calling CascadeWindows.

Comment: @RaymondChen, should this work for all of the opened windows? Because it sometimes just Cascades a current Window. Especially when I call it second and more times.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, if this the answer to this question seems trivial (and if the function can do what I need), in fact it is not, because the problem with passing the hwndParent and the array of child windows is that I have desktop window temporarily missing due to the file's and system corruption (and temporarily can't fix this).

Comment: Your pinvoke declaration is wrong. The last parameter is an array not a single window.

Comment: @RaymondChen, thanks... the declaration was from a first github repo by search with key words "CascadeWindows dllimport" and hwnd there is also <public struct HWND
    {
        public IntPtr ptr;
    }>

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Using C# this can be done like this:

```
        var arrayRange = Process.GetProcesses()
            .Where(x => 
                !string.IsNullOrEmpty(x.MainWindowTitle) &&
                !x.MainWindowTitle.Contains("MainWindow")
            );
            //.Select(x => x.Handle).ToArray();

        int X = 25; int Y = 25;
        foreach (var proc in arrayRange)
        {
            //DLL Import user32.dll 
            user32.MoveWindow(proc.MainWindowHandle, X, Y, 335, 335, 1);
            X += 18; Y += 18;
        }
```

I believe that there is an option in C/C++ to do the same with process handles and MoveWindow from user32.DLL.